# Excel VBA - update BuiltinDocumentProperties using value from different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a "driver" workbook where someone can update values that will be applied to another workbook. The contents of cell B8 of "macros.xlsm" contains the text string I want to use for the author of "report1.xlsx".  I have written the following macro but keep getting a 
"Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the last line.

```
Sub add_properties()

Dim xL As Excel.Application
Set xL = New Excel.Application

Dim mainWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim reportWB As Excel.Workbook

Set mainWB = xL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ga1085\adHoc\macros.xlsm")
Set reportWB = xL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ga1085\adHoc\report1.xlsx")

MsgBox mainWB.Sheets("adHoc").Range("B8").Value

mainWB.Sheets("adHoc").Range("b8").Copy
reportWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties("author").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

I am also using "macros.xlsm" to update margins, headers, etc for "report1.xlsx" - will this work on those too?

Comment: You are looking for something like `reportWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties("author") = mainWB.Sheets("adHoc").Range("B8").Value`???

Comment: Yes. That is what I want.  I tried your line of code but it didn't work. It didn't give an error either.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your workbooks this way. You'll need to add the Microsoft Excel Object Library to your references.

```
Dim xL As excel.Application
Set xL = New excel.Application
Dim mainWB As excel.Workbook
Dim reportWB as excel.Workbook

Set mainWB = xL.Workbooks.Open("macros.xlsm")
Set reportWB = xL.Workbooks.Open("report1.xlsx")
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect your suggestions but my code is still having the same problem with this line.     reportWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties("author").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)  The message box correctly displays the string that I want to use as author.

Comment: Try replacing your copy/paste with: reportWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties("author") = mainWB.Sheets("adHoc").Range("b8").value

Comment: I did try that already per Dirk's recommendation above.  It didn't give me an error but it didn't update the author.

Comment: Are you doing a save? e.g. reportWB.Save? I actually tested it and it works for me... Have you tried doing a debug.print of the property to see if it's set?

Comment: No. It just opens up report1.xlsx - right now it does not save.  I will have to add that to the code.  I never heard of debug.print but will try it.

Comment: Well if you don't save the workbook, it won't keep the property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it to work.  Macros.xlsm is already open and contains the macro that I want to execute.  I didn't have to use PasteSpecial. I think the main difference is that I had to declare a variable "author" then use the variable "author" to update the report workbook.  I am new to VBA - and would appreciate any other input or explanations.  Thank you for your help.

```
Sub add_properties()

Dim author

Dim reportWB As Excel.Workbook

Set reportWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ga1085\adHoc\report1.xlsx")

author = Workbooks("macros.xlsm").Sheets("adHoc").Range("b8").Value

reportWB.BuiltinDocumentProperties("author").Value = author

End Sub
```